# Difference between wear makeup and put on makeup

Tags: grammaticality, word-difference

Do the following sentences have the same meaning?

> 1. She **put on**  makeup.
> 2. She **wore**  makeup.

Comment: Related: [Put on make-up or apply make-up](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/47369/9161)

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not quite the same in meaning. One refers to the act of *applying* the makeup, and the other to *continuing to wear it* afterward.

One can wear makeup without putting it on (by, for example, having someone else apply it), and one can put on makeup but then not wear it (wiping it off immediately, perhaps due to a change of mind or perhaps because one was only putting it on to demonstrate the technique).